# Setting Up of Nginx reverse proxy

Tags: node.js, nginx, amazon-ec2, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have a node application running on an ec2 instance. Node is running on port 5000. I want to access the api from remote.
this is nginx configuration file.

```
    server {
     root /var/www/html;
     index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

     client_max_body_size 20M;
     listen 80;
     listen [::]:80;
     location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
     }
     location /nginx_status {
       # Turn on stats
       stub_status on;
       access_log   off;
     }
    }
```

when I try to `curl` using `curl localhost/nginx_status`
it returns

```
    Active connections: 1 
    server accepts handled requests
    11 11 12 
    Reading: 0 Writing: 1 Waiting: 0
```

Also when I try to access the IP in browser, it shows

```
       Welcome to nginx!

  If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and working.      Further configuration is required.

For online documentation and support please refer to nginx.org.
Commercial support is available at nginx.com.

Thank you for using nginx.
```

But if I try to access the ip_address/nginx_status it shows `404 Error`  for example if I took IP address `123.456.789.098` in browser it shows the above mentioned message and if I took `123.456.789.098/nginx_status` it will return 404 error. Even if I try curl `ip_address/nginx_status`  it is also returning 404 error.

**My question is, How can I access node application running on port 5000 from outside world?**

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately I only see part of your config, is there another server that listens to 80?

You don't use "default_server" for listen either, and without "server_name" I find it difficult to distinguish between them. So maybe another config with the server + port 80 as default_server takes effect. Check in your /etc/nginx/ folder which servers {..} all exist.

The proxy_pass looks correct, if the nodjs server is really listed there, check again whether it is really http or https scheme. For the correct protocol transmission of the proxy_pass.

But you should then add a control for the "stub_status" so that it is information that you do not entrust to everyone, for me it is the case that only one application has access to it internally and under another list what is not released on the internet:

```
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:10081 default_server;

    location /flyingfish_status {
        stub_status on;
        access_log off;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
    }

}
```

I'm curious what you find out! :)